# Does Traefik support port ranges in entrypoints?

Tags: traefik

I have a need to specify about 150 ports for a single application I'm deploying, and I was wondering if there was a reduced way of specifying the ports in the entrypoints other than listing each and every one of them.

If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, at the time of this post it does [not](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/78f1b4216e5c68f1a6df6f87a162bdac414a378d/server/configuration.go#L48).

I've opened a github [feature request issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1677) for anyone interested.